# Are well-orders of the same recursive length recursively isomorphic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability, ordinals

If the ordinal length of $A$ and $B$ is the same recursive ordinal, does it follow that there is a recursive one-one order-preserving correspondence between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE please tell us what you have done/where you are stuck

Comment: What's a recursive length of a well-ordering?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It means the corresponding ordinal is recursive.

Comment: Keith No This fails even for length $\omega$.

Comment: @Andres: So the question just asks if $A$ and $B$ are well-orders of the same type which happened to be a recursive ordinal, then is there a recursive isomorphism between them? This seems strange to ask without adding something about the complexity of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, as stated there is not much more to say. I assume that the actual question has $A,B$ be recursive well-orderings of $\omega$.

Comment: @Andres: That sounds much more plausible, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an [acceptable programming system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_numbering) $(\phi_n)$.

Consider $f$ from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ such that :

1. if $\phi_n(n)$ halts then $f(n)=2\times\left|\{i\le n\;|\;\phi_i(i)\mbox{ halts}\}\right|$
2. if $\phi_n(n)$ nevers halts then $f(n)=1+2\times\left|\{i\le n\;|\;\phi_i(i)\mbox{ never halts}\}\right|$

Hence $f$ is a bijection.

Let $A$ be $\mathbb N$ with the usual order, so $A$ is a set of order length $\omega$ ($\omega$ is recursive).

Let $B$ be $\mathbb N$ with the special order $x\le_B y$ iff  $f(x)\le_A f(y)$, so $B$ is also a set of order length $\omega$.

But $f$ is the order preserving bijection from $B$ to $A$ and $f$ is not recursive.

Comment: Thank you, I'm most grateful for this very instructive counterexample.